# I'm trying to render this glass space helmet, how would you approach this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting, glass

I'm trying to texture this character and I'm stuck on the glass helmet I designed for him. I'm trying to light up his face as it looks lifeless inside the glass. Adding more lights an HDRI doesn't seem to help much. I put a light directly inside and it improved it, but I'm stuck with the point light dot in the render.

I also originally wanted the glass helmet to be a very light and transparent yellow while the character inside is tinted in a saturated orange.

[image: Render with point light inside the glass helmet]

[image: Render without point light inside the glass helmet]

[image: Shader set up for glass]

[image: The original vision. The glass tinted yellow and the character inside tinted orange.]

Comment: Translucent is for objects that should let light pass through *from behind*, you will probably want to use the light path solution here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U4k2.png